# In Vim how to delete last word and replace with another with a map?

Tags: vim

Their is a kind of typing I do a lot :

When I'm everywhere on a word I like to copy it, so i have a simple

```
:nmap <Leader>y yiw
```

And then I'm going to a another word (everywhere on it) to replace with te yanked one, so I write

```
:nnoremap cp "_diwP
```

(cp for clear and paste)

**example :**

previous yanked word : "hello"

It work perfectly if I do cp on "bar" (it replace with the previous yanked)

```
lorem ipsum bar foo
> lorem ipsum hello foo
```

but when the word is at the end of line (ex with 'foo') it gives

```
lorem ipsum bar foo
> lorem ipsum barhello
```

So I have a

```
:nnoremap cP "_diwp
```

The question is how to "merge"

```
:nnoremap cp "_diwP
:nnoremap cP "_diwp
```

in one map ?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ciw` instead of `diw` and then an insert-mode paste:

```
:nnoremap cp "_ciw<C-r>"<Esc>
```

Or, always use `P` but only delete the original word afterward:

```
:nnoremap cp "_yiwPl"_de
```

`"_yiw` is to go to the beginning of the original word (`b` fails if the cursor is already on the first character of the word, and workarounds like `lb` also have pitfalls unless `:set ve+=onemore`).

Comment: I adopted :nnoremap cp "_yiwPl"_de

Thanks a lot, I love your trick with "_yiw and I don't know <<de>> (but it's logic)

Comment: `de` is similar to `dw` but does not delete whitespace before the next word.

Answer (score 1):

My [ReplaceWithRegister plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703) provides a `gr` mapping similar to yours that handles special cases like yours.

Also, you may be interested in the [Smartput plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2095); it changes the `p` / `P` commands to automatically adjust spaces, commas, etc. With it, you can also achieve your goal (though you'd have to use `:nmap`, not `:nnoremap` to enable the plugin in your mappings).